# An error with ets and reading files

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, ets

Disclaimer: I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to make it work.

I'm trying to get the code from [here](https://github.com/CorticalComputer/Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang/tree/master/Ch_19) working.
The setup is an Ubuntu 14.04 64bit machine with Erlang installed.

The sequence of actions is as follows: 
What I'm doing is as follows:

1. clone the code
2. `cd` to the folder with the code and `erl` in terminal
3. `make:all([load]).`
4. `polis:create().`
5. `polis:start().`
6. `benchmarker:start(slidingwindow50).`

The errors I get are:

```
4> benchmarker:start(slidingwindow50).
true Dimensions:4,
Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none

Specie_Id:6.858114617542796e-10 Morphology:forex_trader

******** Population monitor started with parameters:{state,benchmark,test,[], [],undefined,undefined,
undefined,[],0,0,0,0,0, undefined,undefined, undefined,undefined,
undefined,undefined,0.5, 10,10,mathema,inf,10000, inf,<0.274.0>,false}
Initial Tot Evaluations:0

Started Started Started Started Started Started Started

5> =ERROR REPORT==== 16-Mar-2016::14:11:34 === Error in process
<0.287.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{ets,last,['EURUSD15'],[]},{fx,init_state,5,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,375}]},{fx,sim,3,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,284}]}]}

=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Mar-2016::14:11:34 === Error in process <0.288.0> with exit value:
{badarg,[{ets,last,['EURUSD15'],[]},{fx,init_state,5,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,375}]},{fx,sim,3,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,284}]}]}
```

Reviewing the code of  `fx.erl` shows that the problem probably stems from the `ets` part and a `.txt` file not being read from disk and into a table in memory.

**Update**: I've been trying to investigate the function of `fx`. So far, I've had such results:
`fx:sim(anything)` outputs "Started" and makes the shell unresponsive;
`fx:init().` results in

> Initializing FX currency
>   tables:[metadata,'EURUSD15','EURUSD30','EURUSD60'] FX metadata &
>   currency tables initialized and written to file. 
>   ok

`fx:loop().` outputs a lot of

> New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'

with the last line being

> New FOREX_DB update starting with:{2009,6,16,7,30,0,15}

and then

> =ERROR REPORT==== 22-Mar-2016::16:41:26 === Error in process <0.357.0> with exit value:
>   {badarg,[{fx,insert_ForexRaw,2,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,767}]},{fx,updater,1,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,698}]},{fx,heartbeat,3,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,692}]}]}

Running `ets:i().` after `fx:init().` shows no table called `EURUSD15`.

Why may that be, and how can I fix that?

P.S.
If  a working solution is found, I intend to ask for the changes to be merged with the original code (basically, I'll try a push request).

Comment: A `badarg` error from `ets:last` suggests that the table `'EURUSD15'` doesn't exist.

Comment: Correct. So, I wish to understand why it doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

I am familiar with that platform, and we are running it on our machines, we used it as our training material last year.

This is occurring because you didn't start the forex simulator before starting the benchmarker.

Comment: Well, aside from calling me names, you might be very right. And I did read the chapter fully. "You didn't understand it fully" might be more on point, though.

Comment: I'm re-reading the book, and I'm also uncommenting some `io:format` messages. So far I've got a lot of `Started`, `**Starting to process sense signals**`, and a lot of errors. Just running `fx:sim(something).` freezes the erlang shell.
I might be being really thick, but I'll take advice on how to start a forex simulator any time.