# Errors with data insertion in Erlang

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

This question is a follow-up on my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056420/an-error-with-ets-and-reading-files)
I'm trying to understand the workings of [this code](https://github.com/CorticalComputer/Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang/blob/master/Ch_19/fx.erl).
So far, I've been doing the following:

1. clone the code
2. Edit `fx.erl`, mostly uncommenting the `io:format` lines
3. Delete existing files: `EURUSD15` , `EURUSD30`, `EURUSD60`
4. `cd` to the folder with the code and `erl` in terminal
5. `make:all([load]).`
6. `polis:create().`
7. `polis:start().`
8. `fx:init().`
9. `fx:start().`  (as the answer to the previous question recommends)

The console output is like

> New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'
>   TableName:'EURUSD15'
>   CurrencyPair:"EURUSD" SamplingRate:15   CloseL:"1.40720"
>           here{"2009","06","30","00","00","1.40730","1.40750","1.40700",
>                "1.40720","39"}

which suddenly changes to lines like

> ******** ERROR during FX data insertion ********.
>
> TableName:'EURUSD15' CurrencyPair:"EURUSD" SamplingRate:15
>   CloseL:"1.39620"
>           here{"2009","06","25","11","15","1.39720","1.39750","1.39620",
>                "1.39620","196"}

What am I doing wrong, and why are there errors with data insertion?

Answer (score 1):

I did the steps from your question but I skipped some of them and it worked:

```
(...)
New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'
New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'
New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'
New record inserted into table:'EURUSD15'
New FOREX_DB update starting with:{2009,6,16,7,30,0,15}
6>
```

These are steps I did:

```
git clone https://github.com/CorticalComputer/Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang.git
cd Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang/Ch_19/
erl
```

Then in Erlang shell:

```
make:all([load]).
polis:create().
polis:start().
fx:init().
fx:start().
```

I am using `Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1]`.

Comment: Actually, I've just tried basically the same thing with a really clean clone and it worked too. This doesn't answer the question of why I was getting all those errors, but that question is now a lot less relevant.